# mysql unknown column

Tags: mysql

I am using this query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT to_number) AS errors FROM sent_txts
WHERE msg_link_id = 0 AND 
msg_sent_datetime BETWEEN '2010-08-09 07:00:00' AND '2010-09-07 11:59:59'
HAVING to_number IN(SELECT mobile FROM action_6_members WHERE mobile = to_number)
```

However I am getting

> Unknown column 'tada_prod.sent_txts.to_number' in 'where clause'

If I comment out the having the query runs fine.

Here is the sent_txts table

```
CREATE TABLE `sent_txts` (
  `id` int(64) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `msg_link_id` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_class` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_ref` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_number` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_body` text,
  `waiting_for_reply` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tada_error` int(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg_sent_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reply_type` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=256379 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So obviously the column is there.

What is the issue?

---

Here is the explain of the query posted by Jonathan

```
id  select_type  table  type  possible_keys  key  key_len  ref  rows    Extra                           
1   SIMPLE       a      ALL                                     10895                                   
1   SIMPLE       s      ALL                                     256050  Using where; Using join buffer
```

Here is the show create for `action_6_members`:

```
CREATE TABLE `action_6_members` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `draw_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fly_buys` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `signup_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `club` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 = yes, 2 = no',
  `code` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10896 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a HAVING clause relates an aggregate to a value or another aggregate.  What is in the HAVING clause of the question should be in the main WHERE clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT to_number) AS errors
  FROM sent_txts AS s
 WHERE msg_link_id = 0
   AND msg_sent_datetime BETWEEN '2010-08-09 07:00:00'
                             AND '2010-09-07 11:59:59'
   AND to_number IN (SELECT mobile FROM action_6_members AS a
                      WHERE a.mobile = s.to_number)
```

But you should probably make that into a regular join:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.to_number) AS errors
  FROM sent_txts AS s
  JOIN action_6_members AS a ON a.mobile = s.to_number
 WHERE s.msg_link_id = 0
   AND s.msg_sent_datetime BETWEEN '2010-08-09 07:00:00'
                               AND '2010-09-07 11:59:59';
```

Comment: +1: You beat me; I was working on an example using EXISTS.  The JOIN to `action_6_members` risks inflating records if there's more than one child associated to a parent record.

Comment: @OMG: but the DISTINCT undoes any of that damage, does it not?  Also, I think the 'Action 6' people are on a special (mobile phone) rate plan - and this is counting the number of calls sent between the two dates to people on the Action 6 plan - so there will only be one number (at most) in the Action 6 table for any given 'to_number'.

Comment: hmm, dont really like joins but ok :) Just incase, this query should basically select all unique mobile(to_number) from the sent_txts table(based on the where) but only count it if the number exists in the action_6_members, can you see a better way?

Comment: hmm, trying the query above locks up my sql client. (could it be that it is a 30k row table joining a 10k row table?)

Comment: @Hailwood: There's a very decent chance that the join will be more efficient than the IN sub-query (unless the optimizer is smart enough to convert the IN into a join of its own accord), unless the number of people in the Action 6 table is very small (say, under 100).  And joins are usually effective - they are, after all, the bread and butter of an optimizer.  If your DBMS can't manage joins efficiently, get a better DBMS (meaning one that *can* manage joins efficiently).

Comment: @jonothan not quite, a mobile may be in action_6 multiple times.

Comment: @Hailwood: what indexes do you have on sent_txts and action_6_members?  What does the query plan say?

Comment: @Jonothan yeah, I kinda learnt to hate joins when I was working with joining four tables with some having 3Million+ rows

Comment: @Hailwood: please note that schema and cardinality information is helpful.  Both the gross counts and the relationships such as 'a single mobile number may appear several times in action_6_members'.  Since you were asking how to do it, is it safe to assume you didn't have a working query and you don't know how long any alternative would take?

Comment: @Hailwood: your VARCHAR(256) for the 'to_number' column is a bit alarming.  What is the longest to_number actually?  I'd be surprised if it was more than about 20 characters (perhaps with some punctuation).  You're forcing the system to allow for something 25 times that size; which makes for a lot of work.  Do you have an index on sent_txts.to_number?  What about on action_6_members.mobile?  If you have neither, then it is no surprise that your system locks up.  You need at least one of those two indexes.

Comment: I have added what I know to the question, If you require anything else let me know.

Comment: The table was not actually created with this query in mind, this query is also a once off (once it is done it will never be done again).

Comment: What index would you suggest placing on those columns seeing as how both columns can have multiple entries that are identical.

Comment: With regards to the 256 I agree, however I did not create the table :/

Comment: Well, in the DBMS I'm most familiar with, it would be `CREATE INDEX x_mobile ON action_6_members(mobile);` to create a B-Tree index (allowing duplicates) on it.  What that translates to in MySQL is more debatable.  The DBMS I'm most familiar with would most probably auto-index one of the tables - the smaller, presumably action_6_members - for the purposes of answering the query, assuming that the statistics were sufficiently up to date (which, these days, they would be because there's an auotmatic update statistics process).

Comment: Sorry I'm late.  Yes--`DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` would resolve the ultimate data set.  My concern, which I've yet to conclusively test & substantiate, is that two operations vs single when using IN/EXISTS might nullify the implied JOIN benefit.  The alteration using DISTINCT or GROUP BY can also constrain the query.

Comment: @Hailwood: you might also benefit from a BTREE index on '`msg_sent_datetime`'; that could allow the optimizer to pick up the records in the date range faster if there are a lot of records outside the date range.  You'd use this instead of an index on `to_number`.

Comment: Thankyou, I added an index on all three columns and it seems to be working.